# Error after Mono upgrade

Tags: c#, xml, soap, mono, nancy

I was updating `Mono` from repository to a Github version. I wrote a `NancyFx` self-hosted console application in C#.NET 4.5. I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS x64. I bumped into this error and I am not sure if this is

> System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code

or

> System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml:.ctor (System.Xml.XmlDocument): method body is empty.

This is full error stack: http://pastebin.com/MJfp3VsV

Also this is an invoice, but echo works just fine and it's using the same code. On windows it's working just fine. This server is written for Fiscal Verification of Invoices. Invoice is used for verification of invoice and echo, it's just used for testing if server is online. All XAML SOAP requests must be signed with a certificate which was provided by Slovenian Government.

For more info just comment or visit: http://www.datoteke.fu.gov.si/dpr/index_en.html

**Edit:**

Invoice XML scheme: [pastebin.com/P9bYWvhu](http://pastebin.com/P9bYWvhu)

Echo XML scheme: [pastebin.com/XTPWAhJR](http://pastebin.com/XTPWAhJR)

Comment: it looks like this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29665 what version of mono did you compiled?

Comment: Compiled today: Mono JIT compiler version 4.5.0 (master/cde5626 Fri Feb 26 17:18:54 EST 2016)

Comment: Add it as a bug to the mono's bugzilla, there you will get more help.

Comment: Bug report https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=39176.